# WPF Reference control in resourcedictionary

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I created my resource dictionary and can access styles in it, but how (If possible) would I reference an entire control from it?

Here's the resourcedictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="MainWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter> 
        <!--Can access this-->
    </Style>

    <Window x:Key="CustomWindow" Background="Transparent">
        <!--Want to access this-->
    </Window>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here's the main window xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="640" Width="960" >
        <!--setting Style={StaticResource MainWindowStyle} adds the style but I want this window to be replaced by the one in the resourcedictionary-->
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So I basically want to replace the window in the xaml file with the one created in the resource dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly host something like a `UserControl` within another control.

E.g. a `ContentControl`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Window x:Key="CustomUserControl" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Want to access this-->
</Window>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then:

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CustomUserControl}" />
```

I suspect that's not quite what you're after, but it's not clear what you may/may not have within the `Window` that's of interest.

Comment: Ah, glad it helped, a `Window` will fall over if you try to nest it with another control, but if what you require can be put into a `UserControl` things will work. As a slight aside, this isn't the most straightforward way of using a `Control` from elsewhere in your project. Usually you'd add a new namespace, and reference the `Control` in question directly within the XAML, e.g: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb514546%28v=vs.90%29.aspx I suggested this method as it seemed closest to what you wanted. Good luck =D